# How do you pass data between two view controllers using ios 6?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios6.1

I am new to xcode and I do not know how to get the content of one label on my first view controller to be displayed on another label on my second view controller. How would I go about trying to do this? What I am trying to accomplish is someone being able to compute a math equation, taking the resulting answer and displaying the answer on not only view controller one but also view controller two.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 0):

If m not wrong the thing u are trying to accomplish is that you need to display the resulting answer of some math equation on multiple view controller i.e firstviewcontroller as well as secondviewcontroller.

If so, you can store the resulting answer in global variable i.e in your AppDelegate file. So you can access that value in any of your view controller and display it using UILable.